# Jquery mobile grid over background image?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app using jquery mobile and I used `<img>` tag to place background image in the content of the main div which is covering the whole content. I'm trying to position jquery mobile grid over the background image but the grid always displayed directly below the image. Is there a way to position the grid over the image where the image is sent to the back and grid is brought to the front?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the whole content with a background image try this way:

```
.ui-grid-c {
    background : url(../pathTo/yourImage.jpg) !important;
}
```

Comment: thnaks for replying but it's not about covering the whole page with an image (i already did that), I want to place a ui-grid-c over a background image